# LVM: moving physical volumes

Tags: lvm, partition, live-migration

In a virtual server (Debian GNU/Linux 8 amd64) I have the following disks and filesystems:

```
# pvscan 
  PV /dev/vda1   VG vg0   lvm2 [100.00 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/vdb1   VG vg0   lvm2 [46.56 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/vda2   VG vg0   lvm2 [100.00 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/vdc1   VG vg0   lvm2 [60.00 GiB / 60.00 GiB free]
  Total: 4 [306.55 GiB] / in use: 4 [306.55 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                qpeei3-v1nW-pYVR-lK7Y-4wwy-Y4Y4-c9yQEl
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time nomos, 2015-03-17 16:34:05 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                246.56 GiB
  Current LE             63119
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0       243G  135G   98G  59% /
[... no other on-disk filesystems]
```

The root filesystem is ext4.

Since `/dev/vda` has enough room for all my data, I want to remove `/dev/vdb` and `/dev/vdc`. The latter is there as a temporary space only to provide room for the needed maneuvers. The data on `/dev/vdb1` should be moved to `/dev/vda*` before removing `/dev/vdb1`. However the root filesystem currently spans all three partitions `/dev/vda1`, `/dev/vda2` and `/dev/vdb1`.

The problem is I can take the virtual machine down only for very short time periods (a few seconds, just reboots), so I can't reduce the size of the root filesystem, because that requires to unmount it and to keep the server down for quite a long time. I can add other disks though, up to 500GB, if needed.

I've run pvmove to move data off the drive:

```
# pvmove /dev/vdb1 
  Detected pvmove in progress for /dev/vdb1
  /dev/vdb1: Moved: 4.0%
```

and waited until it reached 100%. However pvmove moved the data to `/dev/vdc1`.

```
# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
  /dev/vda1  vg0  lvm2 a--  100.00g     0 
  /dev/vda2  vg0  lvm2 a--  100.00g     0 
  /dev/vdb1  vg0  lvm2 a--   46.56g 46.56g
  /dev/vdc1  vg0  lvm2 a--   60.00g 13.43g
```

And now? I could probably remove `/dev/vdb1`, but I'm stuck with my data on `/dev/vdc1`. What I actually need is to move the allocated inodes of the root filesystem off `/dev/vdb1` to the free filesystem space in `/dev/vda*`. Then I dream I can move `/dev/vdb1` out of the way because the filesystem moved to `/dev/vda*`. I realize it does not work that way automatically, but I'm not able to imagine a migration strategy that lets me do that even manually, without shrinking the root filesystem.

Can you help, please?

Comment: Ahhh....according to the man page for pvmove, the command does allow you to specify BOTH source and destination disks.

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure is only an idea, never tried, but I think it can work:

1. Consider Btrfs pros and cons, and the fact [it isn't really production ready yet](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3dl2nw/is_btrfs_production_ready/) (well, as of 2015, but I couldn't find anything more recent on the subject). Let's assume you want it anyway.
2. Backup backup backup
3. Convert the ext4 filesystem to Btrfs, because Btrfs [supports online migration from ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#In-place_ext2.2F3.2F4_conversion)
4. Shrink the new root filesystem, now Btrfs, because Btrfs [supports online shrinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#Features)
5. Shrink the LVM contaner volume (vg0/root)
6. pvmove data off `/dev/vdb1` (now vdc1 if we consider I've already moved it to `/dev/vdc1`)
7. remove `/dev/vdb1` (or `/dev/vdc1`)
8. say goodbye to ext4 forever

Assuming no other better answers are posted, I will try this and report back here with the details.

Comment: Looks good! Please comment in a month or so to let us know about btrfs stability.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you evaquated your data from `vdb1`. Now:

- remove `/dev/vdb1` using `vgreduce vg0 /dev/vdb1`
- use `pvmove` to remove data from`/dev/vdc1`
- issue `vgreduce vg0 /dev/vdc1` to remove it from the volume group

At this point, your data should be only on `vda*`

Be **very carefull** before removing physical volumes, as you should be **sure** your data were evaquated from the to-be-removed device. And take backups **before doing anything**

Comment: what should be the exact `pvmove` command in order to force it move the data to `/dev/vda*` instead of back to `/dev/vdb1`?

Comment: You had to `vgremove` vdb1 first. Please follow the above instructions.

Comment: Yes, I've already removed vdb1, but: `# pvmove /dev/vdc1
  No extents available for allocation`

Comment: This is because you have no free space on vda, as show by `pvs`

Comment: Yes that's exactly my question in the first place. I actually have only 135GB worth of data and 200GB of capacity on vda. I want to use only vda but I can't shrink the filesystem.

Comment: As your root filesystem is ext4, you should be able to resize it using `resize2fs`. Have you tried it? Anyway, shrinking a filesystem is a complex and potentially dangerous operation, so be sure to have valid backups.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to `resize2fs` a live root filesystem and shrink it to 200 GB. One possible approach is well outlined in the [Unix.SE *How to shrink root filesystem* question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226872/how-to-shrink-root-filesystem-without-booting-a-livecd/227318#227318). It uses `pivot_root` twice and requires a manual restart of most of the OS processes and services; it leads to a loss of recent data, so you cannot use it if you have a living database; and it is fearsome, to put it mildly. But still, it's an alternative that people tried with some success.